Error 500 during WooCommerce API GET request
I am trying to GET all my WooCommerce products using this URL address: https://svetvramu.cz/wp-json/wc/v2/products (using official documentation https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/wp-api-v2.html#list-all-products).
The same URL address using Make.com for the connection establishing (as you can see below - screenshot and whole request).

{
    "message": "Požadavek se nepodařilo dokončit vzhledem k chybě předchozího požadavku.",
    "code": "SC424",
    "suberrors": [
        {
            "message": "Status Code Error: 500",
            "name": "RuntimeError"
        }
    ],
    "debug": [
        [
            "woocommerce2:",
            "request",
            "GET",
            "https://svetvramu.cz/wp-json/wc/v2/products",
            {
                "qs": {
                    "consumer_key": "***",
                    "consumer_secret": "***"
                },
                "headers": {
                    "user-agent": "Make/production"
                },
                "timeout": 40000
            }
        ],
        [
            "woocommerce2:",
            "response",
            500,
            {
                "body": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"cs\">\n<head>\n\t<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\">\n\t\t<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large, noindex, follow' />\n\t<title>WordPress &rsaquo; Chyba</title>\n\t<style type=\"text/css\">\n\t\thtml {\n\t\t\tbackground: #f1f1f1;\n\t\t}\n\t\tbody {\n\t\t\tbackground: #fff;\n\t\t\tborder: 1px solid #ccd0d4;\n\t\t\tcolor: #444;\n\t\t\tfont-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, \"Segoe UI\", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, \"Helvetica Neue\", sans-serif;\n\t\t\tmargin: 2em auto;\n\t\t\tpadding: 1em 2em;\n\t\t\tmax-width: 700px;\n\t\t\t-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);\n\t\t\tbox-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);\n\t\t}\n\t\th1 {\n\t\t\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;\n\t\t\tclear: both;\n\t\t\tcolor: #666;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 24px;\n\t\t\tmargin: 30px 0 0 0;\n\t\t\tpadding: 0;\n\t\t\tpadding-bottom: 7px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t#error-page {\n\t\t\tmargin-top: 50px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t#error-page p,\n\t\t#error-page .wp-die-message {\n\t\t\tfont-size: 14px;\n\t\t\tline-height: 1.5;\n\t\t\tmargin: 25px 0 20px;\n\t\t}\n\t\t#error-page code {\n\t\t\tfont-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace;\n\t\t}\n\t\tul li {\n\t\t\tmargin-bottom: 10px;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 14px ;\n\t\t}\n\t\ta {\n\t\t\tcolor: #2271b1;\n\t\t}\n\t\ta:hover,\n\t\ta:active {\n\t\t\tcolor: #135e96;\n\t\t}\n\t\ta:focus {\n\t\t\tcolor: #043959;\n\t\t\tbox-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #2271b1;\n\t\t\toutline: 2px solid transparent;\n\t\t}\n\t\t.button {\n\t\t\tbackground: #f3f5f6;\n\t\t\tborder: 1px solid #016087;\n\t\t\tcolor: #016087;\n\t\t\tdisplay: inline-block;\n\t\t\ttext-decoration: none;\n\t\t\tfont-size: 13px;\n\t\t\tline-height: 2;\n\t\t\theight: 28px;\n\t\t\tmargin: 0;\n\t\t\tpadding: 0 10px 1px;\n\t\t\tcursor: pointer;\n\t\t\t-webkit-border-radius: 3px;\n\t\t\t-webkit-appearance: none;\n\t\t\tborder-radius: 3px;\n\t\t\twhite-space: nowrap;\n\t\t\t-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;\n\t\t\t-moz-box-sizing:    border-box;\n\t\t\tbox-sizing:         border-box;\n\n\t\t\tvertical-align: top;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\t.button.button-large {\n\t\t\tline-height: 2.30769231;\n\t\t\tmin-height: 32px;\n\t\t\tpadding: 0 12px;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\t.button:hover,\n\t\t.button:focus {\n\t\t\tbackground: #f1f1f1;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\t.button:focus {\n\t\t\tbackground: #f3f5f6;\n\t\t\tborder-color: #007cba;\n\t\t\t-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #007cba;\n\t\t\tbox-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #007cba;\n\t\t\tcolor: #016087;\n\t\t\toutline: 2px solid transparent;\n\t\t\toutline-offset: 0;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\t.button:active {\n\t\t\tbackground: #f3f5f6;\n\t\t\tborder-color: #7e8993;\n\t\t\t-webkit-box-shadow: none;\n\t\t\tbox-shadow: none;\n\t\t}\n\n\t\t\t</style>\n</head>\n<body id=\"error-page\">\n\t<div class=\"wp-die-message\"><p>Na webu došlo k závažné chybě.</p><p><a href=\"https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-troubleshooting/\">Další informace o řešení potíží s WordPressem.</a></p></div></body>\n</html>\n\t",
                "headers": {
                    "date": "Tue, 16 Jul 2024 12:44:31 GMT",
                    "server": "Apache",
                    "x-robots-tag": "noindex",
                    "link": "<https://svetvramu.cz/wp-json/>; rel=\"https://api.w.org/\"",
                    "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
                    "access-control-expose-headers": "X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages, Link",
                    "access-control-allow-headers": "Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type",
                    "expires": "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT",
                    "cache-control": "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, no-store, private",
                    "vary": "User-Agent",
                    "upgrade": "h2,h2c",
                    "connection": "Upgrade, close",
                    "content-security-policy": "upgrade-insecure-requests;",
                    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
                    "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}

I have tried the same GET https://svetvramu.cz/wp-json/wc/v2/products request via Postman - the result is the same (error 500). If I use any specific ID of the product (https://svetvramu.cz/wp-json/wc/v2/products/2, the result is still same.
{
    "code": "internal_server_error",
    "message": "<p>Na webu došlo k závažné chybě.</p><p><a href=\"https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-troubleshooting/\">Další informace o řešení potíží s WordPressem.</a></p>",
    "data": {
        "status": 500
    },
    "additional_errors": []
}

For example, GET on URL https://svetvramu.cz/wp-json/wc/v2/orders works well (200 OK, I see created orders).
Do you have any idea what can be the reason of 500 error? I will really appreciate any help.
